# UITabBar is divided into two part

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want to know why that white part appears above my tabBar and I want to remove that.
[HomeView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GOtc.png)

Like the code in the following pic(i added the code block also), I set my UITabBar().appearance().backgroundColor. And I set the contents in my TabBarItem.
[mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKSrt.png)

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 0.121, green: 0.121, blue: 0.121, alpha: 1)
    //UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .systemPurple
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    
    
    let HomeVC = HomeViewController()
    let ShopVC = ShopViewController()
    
    HomeVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "home-sample"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "home-sample-filled"))
    ShopVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "shop-sample"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "shop-sample-filled"))
    
    self.viewControllers = [HomeVC, ShopVC]
    }
}
```

I wanted know what is that 'white part' and tried several things and I figured out when I set the barTintColor(not just tintColor), the 'white part' changed its color to the color that I have set.(I commented that out)

And the interesting part was that when I changed my view to [ShopView]-(Orange colored background view), that 'white part' disappears like this.
[ShopView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOWFJ.png)

((I just changed the backgroundColor of each view(Home, Shop) to recognize what view it is))

Answer (score 0):

**your method have some issue so try it once**

```
import UIKit

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black], for:.normal)
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: hexStringToUIColor(hex: "12C38C")], for:.selected)
        
        let transUnselectedImage: UIImage = UIImage(systemName: "house")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        let transSelectedImage: UIImage = UIImage(systemName: "house.fill")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        
        let expenseUnselectedImage: UIImage = UIImage(systemName: "heart")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        let expenseSelectedImage: UIImage = UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

        
        tabBar.items![0].image = transUnselectedImage
        tabBar.items![0].selectedImage = transSelectedImage
        
        tabBar.items![1].image = expenseUnselectedImage
        tabBar.items![1].selectedImage = expenseSelectedImage
        

    }  
}
```

**I hope it will be executed successfully**

Comment: I meant the white part above my tab bar but your code seems to manage just the 'tabBarItem'... is it right?